# Good software package to help Maths learning

Tags: matlab, mathematica, maple, sagemath

I'm a mature student enrolling at a Maths degree course soon at the university.
I'd like to be able to use some software package to help me visualize equations, graphs, play around with variables with some sort of sliders, watch the results, use that to help me understand Maths better.

Not interested in "real world" stuff for now (realistic simulations for engineering purposes and stuff like that). Just a good piece of software that I can use to better understand and manipulate and visualize mathematical principles; but at the same time something user friendly enough to allow me to concentrate more on the maths side of things, rather than spending all of my limited time fighting with the software to achieve the most menial of tasks.

I understand there's always a learning curve involved when picking up a new piece of software, I'm not afraid of that. But different packages will have different curve steepnesses...

Don't care if it's commercial or open source software.

I've been reading about Mathematica, Maple, Matlab and something called Sage. Looks like these are the main players in this market.

Any opinions on which software should I invest in to help me with my studies?
Again, mostly to **visualize and understand** Maths. 
No need for anything more elaborate for now, although no problem if the potential for growth is already there.

Thanks!

Comment: Matlab/Mathematica are your friends.

Comment: i would go for something along the lines of Geogebra or Geometer's Sketchpad. The strengths are the ability to drag a diagram around, see how things change when you alter conditions. I learned with actual graph paper, actual compass and straightedge. The thing that is clearest to me about today's students is that they cannot actually see much of anything, no practice with drawing. Similar with 3-d visualization, i used to make models of polyhedra and so on. I am, of course, very old.

Comment: I agree that both of these are worth looking at, and Geogebra is free. And...I agree, I'd probably construct the Euler line using a pencil , paper , straightedge  and compass , (or perhaps download a document that had the results I needed). I love the diagrams in a journal like Forum Geometricorum and may put in the time to learn one of these eventually.

Comment: Now that i think of it, I do recommend http://zometool.com/ and those sets with the bar magnets and little steel balls. To some extent the things you can build readily are directed by the design of the toy, but the better ones still allow some flexibility. http://www.amazon.com/CMS-Magnetics%C2%AE-Magnetic-Building-Sets/dp/B000IOK5I0

Comment: Wow, that's what I need , a method of constructing Zonohedra!

Comment: @Alan, yes, those are very good. I wound up looking for sale of bulk items, 300 of the same piece or the like. Much cheaper than buying multiple sets. I bought enough to show a hugely extended tessellation of $\mathbb R^3$ by rhombic dodecahedra. If I did it again I would wear gloves, you need to tighten each piece as you go, and plan things out. We took photographs but they don't really get it across.

Comment: I do remember, i got enough to have one rhombic dodecahedron cell in the center, surrounded by another twelve, finally an extra four at the corners, the result being a tetrahedron, the Voronoi cells of the closest sphere packing of 20 balls in a triangular pyramid, four spheres along each edge... Good thing to do once.

Comment: Check out [Wolfram alpha](http://wolframalpha.com) online. For calculus/algebra I use [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net) (open source), SAGE contains it for some operations.

Comment: @ Will Jagy That's great, I spent at least part of my childhood trying to understand what Buckminster Fuller was talking about. ... and what H.S.M. Coxeter was carefully writing down --   best since Hilbert and Cohn-Vossen.

Comment: @Alan, along with Coxeter's Regular Polytopes I recommend two inexpensive books, Shapes, Space, and Symmetry by Alan Holden, in which he made cardboard or wire models and took photographs, and Platonic and Archimedean Solids by Daud Sutton. There are also various recent expensive books, Cambridge U. Press and the like. Cannot find what I was thinking about, but here are a few from their site: http://www.cambridge.org/us/search?query=polytopes&iFeelLucky=false&currentTheme=Academic_v1&searchSubmitProducts=

Comment: @Will Jagy Thanks for that, It's bookmarked.

Comment: Many universities make good mathematics software available to their students. Check out what your school has to offer before you spend money on something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you happen to own a Macintosh, the application named Grapher ( it's inside the utilities folder) seems to be a great application for visualizing results. It is very easy to start out with and can produce some very involved visualizations.

SAGE is free but it's visualization capabilities depend on getting Gnuplot to work correctly. I haven't gotten results equal to the commercial packages (the three Ms).
Mathematica has so much support that I would probably recommend it above Maple and Matlab. Although , to some extent this will depend on getting a hands on copy to play with. Although I once owned a copy of Matlab and have it running on a much older machine I can't get a newer version to play around with, cost is prohibitive for me. So Maple is number two, I'm still learning it. Your results will certainly vary. Try SAGE first, maybe you'll have better luck with the Graphics package.

Comment: Thank you, @Alan 
Yes I use a Mac, and I find the Grapher application very useful. Although it looks a bit limited and doesn't allow some kind of interactive interface that I can "touch and drag" to see changes in real time. I'm not a particularly smart or fast guy, so I think a tool like that would probably help me visualize and understand the concepts better.
But I will play around with the trial versions of most of them, for sure.

Regarding Matlab prices, the Home edition is marked at 105€/$145: http://www.mathworks.com/pricing-licensing/index.html?intendeduse=home&prodcode=ML

Comment: Really, I'll take a look at it, I mean I own an old copy, but I'll take a look at the pricing, I really thought it was out of reach. Thanks!

Comment: Bought a copy of Matlab today, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: You're welcome, @Alan 
Who would have thought that I'd be able to help someone on my first post here? ;)